# "Binding" file format to open it with Java program by default

Tags: java, file

Is it possible to "bind" file format to open it with Java program by default?

I am developing an mapper application which is saving all maps in .MAP format which can be opened using the same application. I want to open my Java program when user is opening file in this format. If this is possible, how can I do this on different platforms, especially Linux, Windows and Mac (because I guess there is no multiplatform way to program this)?

Best if it would be possible without using any installers and wrapping .jar into formats like .exe, but if this is not possible I will just make many versions of my program for different systems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No experience, but [JDIC](http://download.java.net/javadesktop/swinglabs/releases/0.8/docs/api/org/jdesktop/jdic/filetypes/AssociationService.html) is intended to associate a file type.